# How do you edit .tmp file removal settings?

Tags: file-upload, upload, struts2, tmp

1. Using Struts 2: when will the .tmp file - that gets created after uploading a file - be deleted?
2. How can you customize when the .tmp file should be deleted? Do you have to create a copy of it?

Please don't be shy to give some code :)

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229328/while-trying-to-upload-the-image-in-struts2-the-image-is-not-uploading-msg-unabl

Comment: I don't think people are shy about giving code! They just need to know that people asking questions have written some codes for themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** This depends on which version of S2 you're talking about.

- S2.2.1 and prior: the file upload interceptor deleted temp files.
- S2.2.3 and above: the filter dispatchers start the deletion process, changed due to [WW-3490](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3490).

**2.** Assuming you're using a recent version, it might be possible to inject a tweaked `Dispatcher`, although it's not immediately obvious how–if it is, that's the easiest change at the core level.

The easiest approach from a *practical* standpoint is to copy files in the action, which is also pretty fast on any reasonable file system.

Comment: I have used S2.3.15.2 In My application . But when i am going to upload any file its create many `.tmp` with file 1KB size in my temp folder of tomcat and its not deleted automatically . SO why this happen ? I want to delete this all temp file .

Comment: @ankit337 No idea, it shouldn't, if you're not uploading many 1K files. If you're having a specific issue, please ask a new question, providing all relevant configuration, action, etc. details.