# How to delete .tmp file in fileupload struts2

Tags: java, tomcat, file-upload, struts2, temporary-files

I have used `file-upload` (common fileuplod) in `strtus-2.3.15.3` .
There is one Form in my `.jsp` with multiple field with many diff type(textfield,textarea,hidden,file) including `FILE` and obvious `SUBMIT`.

When i submit form by selecting one file and enter some text in all other field its generated `.tmp` file in mention temp folder . Only `.tmp` file related to file field is going to delete after uploading my file to myfolder but rest of `.tmp`(with 1kb size) file is remaing as its .

```
List items = upload.parseRequest(servletRequest);
```

This line in below code generate `.tmp` file for all field which have some value (if you do not enter any text in text field it not generated) .

`MonitoredMultiPartRequest.java` **:**

```
public void parse(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, String saveDir)
            throws IOException
    {

        System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "D:\\ankit");

        UploadListener listener = new UploadListener(servletRequest);
        // Create a factory for disk-based file items
        FileItemFactory factory = new MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory(listener);
        // Create a new file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

    }
```

`MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory` :

```
public class MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory extends DiskFileItemFactory
{
    HttpServletRequest request;

    public MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory(OutputStreamListener listener, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        this.listener = null;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.request = request;
        setTrackers();
    }

    public void setTrackers()
    {
        FileCleaningTracker fileCleaningTracker = FileCleanerCleanup.getFileCleaningTracker(request.getServletContext());
        File repository = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(DiskFileItemFactory.DEFAULT_SIZE_THRESHOLD, repository);
        factory.setFileCleaningTracker(fileCleaningTracker);
        super.setFileCleaningTracker(fileCleaningTracker);
        super.setRepository(repository);
    }

    public MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory(int sizeThreshold, File repository, OutputStreamListener listener)
    {
        super(sizeThreshold, repository);
        this.listener = null;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public FileItem createItem(String fieldName, String contentType, boolean isFormField, String fileName)
    {
        MonitoredDiskFileItem result = new MonitoredDiskFileItem(fieldName, contentType, isFormField, fileName, getSizeThreshold(), getRepository(), listener);
        FileCleaningTracker tracker = getFileCleaningTracker();
        if (tracker != null)
        {
            tracker.track(result.getTempFileOfDistFileItem(), result);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private OutputStreamListener listener;
}
```

`MonitoredDiskFileItem` :

```
public class MonitoredDiskFileItem extends DiskFileItem
{

    public MonitoredDiskFileItem(String fieldName, String contentType, boolean isFormField, String fileName, int sizeThreshold, File repository, OutputStreamListener listener)
    {
        super(fieldName, contentType, isFormField, fileName, sizeThreshold, repository);
        mos = null;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream()
            throws IOException
    {
        if (mos == null)
            mos = new MonitoredOutputStream(super.getOutputStream(), listener);
        return mos;
    }

    public File getTempFileOfDistFileItem()
    {
        return super.getTempFile();
    }

    private MonitoredOutputStream mos;
    private OutputStreamListener listener;
}
```

`UploadListener` :

```
public class UploadListener implements OutputStreamListener, Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int totalToRead = 0;
    private int totalBytesRead = 0;
    private int percentDone = 0;
    private int previou_percentDone = 0;
    private long uploadspeed = 0;
    private long starttime;
    private long stTime, EndTime;
    HttpSession session;
    private int count = 0;

    public UploadListener(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        totalToRead = request.getContentLength();
        session = request.getSession();
    }

    public void start()
    {
        session.setAttribute("percentageDone", 0);
        session.setAttribute("speed", 0);
        starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        stTime = starttime;

    }

    public String getMessage()
    {
        return "" + totalBytesRead + " bytes have been read (" + percentDone + "% done)  ";
    }

    public void bytesRead(int bytesRead)
    {
        totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead + bytesRead;

        if (100.00 * totalBytesRead > totalToRead)
        {
            previou_percentDone = percentDone;
            percentDone = (int) Math.round(100.00 * totalBytesRead / totalToRead);
            if (previou_percentDone < percentDone)
            {
                long speed = 0;
                try
                {
                    double TimediffInSecond = (System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime) / 1000;
                    if (TimediffInSecond > 0)
                        speed = Math.round(((totalBytesRead) / TimediffInSecond) / 1048576);
                    else
                        speed = totalBytesRead / 1048576;

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }


    }

    public void done()
    {
        EndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        session.setAttribute("percentageDone", 100);
        session.setAttribute("speed", 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void error(String message)
    {
        // System.out.println(message);
    }

    public long getUploadspeed()
    {
        return uploadspeed;
    }

    public void setUploadspeed(long uploadspeed)
    {
        this.uploadspeed = uploadspeed;
    }

}
```

`EDIT` **:**

1> Why this `.tmp` file is generated for fields (textarea ,hidden,textfield) .
How can we prevent this ?

2> i want to stop generating `.tmp` file for all field except where `type='file'`(file field) .

3> Otherwise, how can i delete this all `.tmp` file ?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need Commons libraries for this, nor a Servlet.

You are using Struts2, so don't reinvent the wheel and use **Actions** and **Interceptors**.

You can find the code to [upload multiple files with Struts2 in this exhaustive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17212916/1654265) , and a little improvement by [creating a custom object in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19117057/1654265).

I feel the need to link [this nice answer from BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet) too, when talking about fileUpload through Servlet.

---

**Let's come to your specific question:** you are using a `MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory`, (you didn't specified which of the many implementations growing on the web, but it is likely that it is ->) a Subclass of the standard [`org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItemFactory.html).

In the JavaDoc it is well explained that:

> This implementation creates `FileItem` instances **which keep their
>   content either in memory**, for smaller items, **or in a temporary file on
>   disk**, for larger items. **The size threshold, above which content will
>   be stored on disk, is configurable**, as is the directory in which
>   temporary files will be created.
>
> If not otherwise configured, the default configuration values are as
>   follows:
>
> - Size threshold is 10KB.
> - Repository is the system default temp directory, as returned by 
>     `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`.
>
> NOTE: Files are created in the system default temp directory with predictable names. This means
>   that a local attacker with write access to that directory can perform
>   a `TOUTOC` attack to replace any uploaded file with a file of the
>   attackers choice. The implications of this will depend on how the
>   uploaded file is used but could be significant. When using this
>   implementation in an environment with local, untrusted users,
>   `setRepository(File)` MUST be used to configure a repository location
>   that is not publicly writable. In a Servlet container the location
>   identified by the ServletContext attribute
>   `javax.servlet.context.tempdir` may be used.
>
> **Temporary files, which are created for file items, should be deleted
>   later on. The best way to do this is using a `FileCleaningTracker`,
>   which you can set on the `DiskFileItemFactory`. However, if you do use
>   such a tracker, then you must consider the following: Temporary files
>   are automatically deleted as soon as they are no longer needed. (More
>   precisely, when the corresponding instance of File is garbage
>   collected.) This is done by the so-called reaper thread, which is
>   started automatically when the class FileCleaner is loaded. It might
>   make sense to terminate that thread, for example, if your web
>   application ends. See the section on "Resource cleanup" in the users
>   guide of commons-fileupload.**

From [Commons FileUpload Documantation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html)

> ## ***Resource cleanup***
>
> This section applies only, if you are using the `DiskFileItem`. In other
>   words, it applies, if your uploaded files are written to temporary
>   files before processing them.
>
> Such temporary files are deleted automatically, if they are no longer
>   used (more precisely, if the corresponding instance of `java.io.File` is
>   garbage collected. This is done silently by the
>   `org.apache.commons.io.FileCleaner` class, which starts a reaper thread.
>
> This reaper thread should be stopped, if it is no longer needed. In a
>   servlet environment, this is done by using a special servlet context
>   listener, called `FileCleanerCleanup`. To do so, add a section like the
>   following to your web.xml:
>
> ```
> <web-app>
>   ...
>   <listener>
>     <listener-class>
>       org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.FileCleanerCleanup
>     </listener-class>
>   </listener>
>   ...
> </web-app>
> ```
>
> ***Creating a DiskFileItemFactory***
>
> The `FileCleanerCleanup` provides an instance of
>   `org.apache.commons.io.FileCleaningTracker`. This instance must be used
>   when creating a
>   `org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory`. This should be
>   done by calling a method like the following:
>
> ```
> public static DiskFileItemFactory newDiskFileItemFactory(ServletContext context
>                                                            , File repository) {
>     FileCleaningTracker fileCleaningTracker
>           = FileCleanerCleanup.getFileCleaningTracker(context);
>     DiskFileItemFactory factory
>           = new DiskFileItemFactory(DiskFileItemFactory.DEFAULT_SIZE_THRESHOLD,
>                                       repository);
>     factory.setFileCleaningTracker(fileCleaningTracker);
>     return factory;
> }
> ```
>
> ***Disabling cleanup of temporary files***
>
> To disable tracking of temporary files, you may set the
>   `FileCleaningTracker` to null. Consequently, created files will no
>   longer be tracked. In particular, they will no longer be deleted
>   automatically.

Then you can:

1. **set an higher threeshold, to keep everything in memory** instead that using temporary files, or
2. **follow Apache guidelines to properly wipe temporary files** when they're not needed anymore.

Comment: `@Andrea .` thanks for respond , I have implemented this in my application and now i don't want to change whole flow (i reinvent this interceptors cause i want to track amount of file being uploaded each time progress bar ).

Comment: my question is why this `.tmp` file is generated for other field like `textarea` (with some value) , How can i prevent this from generate `.tmp` file . (if i go for your suggestion than after same issue this occur cause its generated during ` parse servletrequest`)

Comment: hello can you help how and when can i call `newDiskFileItemFactory()` method

Comment: what happen if we increase `ThresholdSize` ?Should it decrease performance ?  which is best create .tmp file or keep in memory (according to performance) ?

Comment: If you increase the `ThresholdSize`, you will need more RAM and less HD space. It won't decrease performances (it will increase them, since RAM is faster than HD, but probably in a non even noticeable way...). Which is best depends on your needs: do you want to fill the RAM or the HD ?

Comment: Sure i will accept answer if i will get successes .
I have edited my post . (one solution is increase thresholdsize so my 1kb file is haven't created tmp file and no need to worry about) . But why this tracker is not able to delete this all file . By default tracker is always `null` than after how `tmp` (which is used for file upload) is going to delete how this `tmp` file is being track and other `tmp` file are not deleted  ?

Comment: Other Problem i face . If i not set threshold value (default 10kb). So when i am going to upload file less 10kb size is not going to upload in my folder cause its size found 0 while is going to copy .