# Struts 2 - Deleting temp files created for file upload

Tags: struts2, struts-config

Struts create temp files as part of file upload . I have specified my own location (struts.multipart.saveDir) for creating the temp files. My problem is that the temp files that are getting created are not getting deleted. I was under the impression that the framework would delete the files. Is my understanding correct ? If so then mine is not working as expected.  I couldn't get a proper answer any where online . Struts 2 documentation on temp directors (http://struts.apache.org/docs/file-upload.html#FileUpload-TemporaryDirectories) doesn't specify any thing either.

Can some one help figure out

1. Should struts frame work be deleting temp files it create as part of
   upload ?
2. If the answer for 1 is yes, Is there some thing specific we need to
       do ?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19544311/1654265

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete .tmp file in fileupload struts2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543422/how-to-delete-tmp-file-in-fileupload-struts2)